# Time taken to write to a file decreasing for subsequent program run

Tags: java, caching, io

I wrote a java program in Eclipse which writes 30 million lines to a file.
The first time i ran this code, the time taken to write to the textfile(foo.txt) took approximately 104 seconds.
I deleted the textfile(foo.txt), which i had written the lines to, and ran the program again. This time it took 61 seconds.

I continued this process and the time taken for writing to the file kept decreasing each time i ran the program. The recorded time to write to the file turned out to be as follows:

(In seconds,approx values)
104->61->39->25->18->16->16->16->...

What i observed is that the time taken to write to the textfile(foo.txt) kept decreasing until it became constant at around 16 seconds.

My java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileWriter;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class fileWrite {  
private static int file_sz = 30000000;  
private static final String line = "Help I am a chinese guy trapped in a fortune cookie factory!!";
 /*
No offense meant to any Chinese person, i apologise in advance if i have hurt your feelings.
*/ 

private static void write(List<String> list, Writer writer)throws IOException {
    long start  = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(String list_el: list){
        writer.write(list_el);
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((end-start)/1000f + "seconds");

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        File file = new File("foo.txt");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>(file_sz);
        for(int i = 0;i<file_sz;++i){
            records.add(line);
        }
        write(records,writer);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Questions i would like to ask are:

Why did the time taken to write to the file become constant?
Is the time decrease related to the cache somehow?

I would be really grateful if someone could shed light on what is happening behind the scenes. Any links which explain the working of the system in detail would be welcome too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question precisely without knowing more about the system you're running the program on. A good test for triangulating the source of this effect would be to write a program in a different language that does the same thing.

Comment: I have a 64-bit Operating System,8GB RAM & an i7 Processor. I am running the program on windows. I shall try running it in a different language and also on a different OS. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably your Operating System and specifically your file system doing its job.

File systems represent files as a series of blocks or extents; this way, files don't have to continuously fit on your storage medium.

First time you wrote your file, your file system started with the first free block it could find, and when that was written to, got the next free one, added it to the list of blocks in your file, and so on.

As the file grew, the file system gave up on finding blocks between other blocks, but got a continuous chunk of free space on your medium, and just always appended the next block to your file. That both reduces file system overhead as well as, in the case of hard drives, reduces latency due to the write header slowly going to a new position.

Now, after you delete your original file, the file system-internal pointer to "first free block" might still be in the area of contiguous free space.

Also, modern operating systems might be smart and understand that your program always opens one file in a specific folder for access, and puts much data there, and hence might optimize the way the file system works.

The most likely thing to happen is that both Java and your OS have write caches in RAM, which store data written to a file before/while it is actually written to disk. These caches are elastic; as you write much data, the Operating system takes up more free RAM for write caching (e.g. away from read caches). After your program finishes, the write cache is no longer needed -- but since it's not used in any other way, the next time you write a large file, the Operating System can very quickly assign that memory to a write cache.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation,it really helped. I would like to ask though, are the write caches not freed at all? What happens if the OS allocates a huge amount of RAM for the write cache? Won't the other processes take a hit?

Comment: The OS won't take away memory already mapped into processes' memory space (unless that page was already swapped or so, but then, there probably wouldn't be much space for write caches, anyway). So "taking a hit" doesn't apply here, unless another process starts asking for memory. Getting that memory, in the worst case, might then take as much time as necessary to write data from cache to disk.